# Adding silent renew entry point to React(create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a React application created using the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) module. I have recently been asked by a client to integrate with oidc. For this purpose I'm using [redux-oidc](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc), as I already have redux working in my app as well.

We managed to integrate my application into their Identity server and I'm able to sign in and get the user token stored in redux. The problem is that I'm struggling to setup [silent renew](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc/wiki/4.-Silent-renew) in my create-react-app application as I have to add an additional entry point. Is there a way to add an additional entry point to `silent_renew/index.js` without ejecting create-react-app?

Currently I've create a folder called silent_renew containing an `index.js` file. This folder also contains a `silent_renew.html` file with not much in it (See: [example app](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example) similar to my folder structure).

Comment: The purpose of `create-react-app` is to provide a simple way do zero-configuration apps.  Plugging `loadUser` with the store would be ok, but I'm afraid changing the webpack configuration and adding this entry point would defies what CRA is and would require an eject. Probably not the answer you are looking for, leaving it as a comment but tell me if that could be one.

Comment: Thanks @Aperçu. Yeah this was sort of my assumption reading through 100's of posts. I'm not familiar with Webpack at all! I did eject my app but not sure how to go about adding an additional entry route to my app. I looked everywhere but there doesn't seem to be much on adding entry points to the ejected create-react-app webpack config files, unless I missed it. Do you know of anything or even better do you have any idea how? If you do PLEASE add it as an answer. If it works, I'll award the bounty immediately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the landing page for silent_renew is a just a simple html page, you could bypass webpack. Just put the following file in the public folder. Also, include a copy of the oidc-client.min.js library in the same folder.

public/silent_renew.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      new Oidc.UserManager().signinSilentCallback().then()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works at my site in the develepment config. For the production config I have the following in mind (I did not test it yet but I'm pretty confident this is the way forward...).

public/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('.'))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (path.extname(req.path).length > 0) {
    next()
  } else if (path.dirname(req.path).indexOf('silent_renew') > -1) {
    req.url = '/silent_renew.html'
    next()
  }
  else if (path.dirname(req.path).indexOf('callback') > -1) {
    req.url = '/callback.html'
    next()
  } else {
    req.url = '/index.html'
    next()
  }
})

app.listen(3000)
```

As soon as create-react-app supports multiple entry points (I hope this happens soon for enterprise login scenario's) this code becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 11):

You can also take the approach of loading the main bundle in the `iframe` and capturing the path as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4480#issuecomment-411444774).

Then you don't need to deal with exposing a path to load the oidc client lib (`oidc-client.min.js` or `redux-oidc.js`) or dumping it's content somewhere.

index.js/ts

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { processSilentRenew } from 'redux-oidc';
import App from './App';

if (window.location.pathname === '/silent-renew') {
  processSilentRenew();
} else {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

Please note that `/silent-renew` request performance can be potentially  *negatively* impacted by large files that loaded along with the application. Some thoughts on it in the [comment](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc/issues/48#issuecomment-315422236).

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by simply adding a route instead of using a separat endpoint. My setup is a create-react-app with redux, redux-oidc & react-router.

I configured the `UserManager` to use

```js
{
    silent_redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ""}/silent_renew`
}
```

I added this route in my react-router:

```js
<Route exact={true} path={"/silent_renew"} component={SilentRenewComponent} />
```

The `SilentRenewComponnent` is a simple function component which calls the `redux-oidc` function to process the redirect.

```js
import React from "react";
import { processSilentRenew } from "redux-oidc";

export const SilentRenewComponent = () => {
    processSilentRenew();
    return(
        <div>SilentRenewComponent</div>
    );
};
```

Comment: seems to be working, but may I ask you please, in your approach you also developed something like history.push to previous component and persist-redux ? (so that user do not redirects to SilentComponent UI, and redux values of the component he was working before redirect call, persist)

Answer (score 1):

As previously said, changing the webpack configuration of `create-react-app` would defies what the purpose of this project is, providing a way to do React with zero-configuration.

I'm afraid the solution would be to eject your app, which is irreversible.

After doing so, create the `silent_renew` directory at the root of your project with the `index.js` and `index.html` file, create a `store` for redux as seen [here](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example/blob/master/src/store.js) (you probably don't need a lot of this stuff, like sagas, the router and logger middleware, just take the `loadUser` logic and store creation), import the store in the `src/index.js` file and create a redux `Provider`, like [this](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example/blob/master/src/app/app.js).

Then, you can modify `config/webpack.config.dev.js` and follow what we can see at the [redux-oihc-example](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example/blob/master/webpack.config.js) webpack conf. Add `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `CommonsChunkPlugin` for `silentRenew`, and the additional entry point.

What's a bit upsetting about CRA is that their webpack configuration for dev and prod are totally separated and do not extend a shared one. You'll have to do this operation in both prod and dev configs, or extend one other conf file to prevent redundancy, like [this](https://github.com/SIGSEV/minus/blob/master/webpack/dev.js#L9) for example.

---

I would also advice you to use another simple scaffold, CRA is good when you don't have anything special to do unlike what you want (and probably more in the future). Ejecting will create a lot of files and code that you don't even need in your own codebase. A friend and I made a [minimalist one](https://github.com/SIGSEV/minus), but I'm sure there is plenty of better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a custom webpack loader if you haven't ejected:

> We don't intend to provide Webpack specific overrides because it will be very fragile. People will start depending on specific loaders and plugins and we won't be able to improve the overall experience.

source: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/99#issuecomment-234657710

If you want to add a new specific entry file you first need to `yarn eject` then edit `config/webpack.config.dev.js:34` and `config/webpack.config.prod.js:55`.
The same is valid for adding new webpack loaders.

Comment: Thanks @enapupe. Nay idea on what the best way to do this is? I have ended up ejecting my config. Looked through the webpack configs ejected and tried adding a new path. Couldn't get it working. I'm not too clued up on Webpack as I've never had this requirement. Looked at numerous post on google but not much info on this topic for create-react-app

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I think that you should probably open a new question specifically to this new issue. I recommend that you share some files so we can reproduce what's going wrong. Did you get any errors? What exactly is not working?